# AutoHotkey able to capture firefox tab?

Tags: firefox, autohotkey, windows-7-x64

It is a bit beyond of my knowledge, so I copy&pasted the whole script.

But I was rejected with a message, which reads, (Firefox version is 28.0) Anybody please help me.

Error:  Call to nonexistent function.
Specifically: Acc_Get( ... ...

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
WinGet, windows, List, Mozilla Firefox
Loop %windows% {
    hwnd := windows%A_Index%
    ;// Acc_Get(Cmd, ChildPath="", ChildID=0, WinTitle="", WinText="", ExcludeTitle="", ExcludeText="")
    page_tab_list := Acc_Get("object", "application.grouping2.property_page.tool_bar3.page_tab_list", "", "ahk_id" hwnd)
    For Each, tab in Acc_Children(page_tab_list)
        if tab.accName(0) = "https://www.apple.com/" {
            tab.accDoDefaultAction(0) ;// remove line to NOT activate tab
            WinActivate ahk_id %hwnd%
            break 2
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to show some code.  Probably, you should read this site's FAQ, too, and do a search for anything that would help you before you ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[autohotkey]+firefox+tab  But, to answer your question, yes it is possible.

Comment: To clarify, So you are using `IfWinExist` to detect if a firefox tab exists, that does not seem to work?

Comment: Yes, that is the only one I can think of. You mean, I have to take another way to make it?

Comment: The ahk forum has some pointers, like [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/8553-how-to-find-a-url-on-firefox-with-multi-tabs/) or [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/89078-find-not-active-firefox-tab-browser/). But I am not near a windows pc to test if that still works with recent firefox versions.

Comment: Consulting the URL Wimmel suggested, I edited my question. I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: @ragna_ravc You are getting `Error: Call to nonexistent function. Specifically: Acc_Get( ... ...` because you are trying to call a function `Acc_Get` that does not exists. You wrote that you pasted whole code of your script. In your script function `Acc_Get` is not defined. You need to define `Acc_Get` function.

Answer (score 0):

This script simply walks through all tabs until it finds the correct one, via the page title in the window title. Sleep timer can be adjusted.

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2

needle := "Stack Overflow"

WinActivate, Firefox
Loop {
  WinGetTitle, title
  IfWinNotActive, Firefox
    break
  if (InStr(title,needle))
    Break
  Else
    send ^{PgUp}
  sleep 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't take all the dependencies from the source. You are missing the required Acc Library.
; Acc.ahk https://github.com/sancarn/ACC.AHK/blob/master/AccV2.ahk
; ACC Tutorial: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=40590